# Why this 'adding index migration' won't work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I did `bundle exec rake db:migrate` with migration file below.

on terminal it looked it went successfully like this

```
==  AddIndexToCommunity: migrating ============================================
-- add_index(:communities, [:community_name, :title, :user_id], {:name=>:communities_idx})
   -> 0.0452s
==  AddIndexToCommunity: migrated (0.0456s) ===================================
```

However, if I take a look at phpMyAdmin's Structure section, it won't display the index generated by this migration.
Why?

**migration file**

```
class AddIndexToCommunity < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_index :communities, [:community_name, :title, :user_id], :name=>:communities_idx
  end

  def self.down
    remove_index :communities, [:community_name, :title, :user_id], :name=>:communities_idx
  end
end
```

Comment: are you sure it's not related to phpmyadmin not showing it ? did you check directly in the command line interface ? as shown here : http://www.electrictoolbox.com/list-table-structure-mysql-command-line/ Basically you just need to do `show keys from communities;`

Comment: When you add index to associations, it's better to add index on community.id - user.id association (not community.name or user.title).

Comment: @itsnikolay I know that. But I use `to_param` that's the reason why:)

Comment: @pjam Thanks but it says ERROR 1046 (3D000): No database selected :(

Comment: @pjam Thanks I could do that. but it was the same result as what it show in phpMyAdmin:( It seems index is not added properly

Comment: This won't be applied to existing records?